# Size of scene for iphone 3.5-inch and 4-inch in cocos2d v3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have some trouble with size of scene.I get always same size UIScreen, therefore I can't determine screen size, I always get "320x480" at 3.5-inch iphone & 4-inch iphone. How can I start getting screen sizes instead of "320x480"? Thanks in advance  http://lvkr.ru/u49S4A.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size
```

?

Examining the size's height and width should return 320x480 for a 3.5 inch screen, and 320x568 for a 4 inch screen.

Comment: I tryed it, but I get always 320x480, maybe somewhere in settings of cocos2d indicated that the size of the screen 320x480?But I looked main setting and found fixed size and changed it to flexible, but nothing has changed.         CCSetupScreenMode: CCScreenModeFlexible

Answer (score 0):

```
use this for checking whether the device is iPhone 4 or 3.5 inch,then get y position or height for controller or view


+(BOOL)isDeviceiPhone5
{
    BOOL iPhone5 = FALSE;

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        iPhone5 = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        iPhone5 = FALSE;
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
    }
    return iPhone5;

}


+(CGRect )getFrameFor_iPhone4_height:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 87.0;
    return frame;
}
+(CGRect )getFrameFor_iPhone4_yPos:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 87.0;
    return frame;
}
```

Comment: It's very good idea, but I get 320x480 from 3.5-inch and 4-inch... http://lvkr.ru/u49S4A.jpg